# Make a slideshow on click without a plugin

Tags: jquery, slideshow, image-gallery

I have a image gallery and i want to change the image whenever i click in the left/ right button.
I know that have this function on Cycle Plugin, but i don't want to use too much plugins in my page.
So i tried to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery a').click(function(){
        var path = 'images/display/'
        var i = 2;
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.lightbox').removeClass('preloader').fadeIn();
        $('.display').html('<img src="'+path+i+'.jpg" />').addClass('imgdisplay');
    });
    $('.leftnav').click(function(){
        i++;
    });
    $('.rightnav').click(function(){
        i--;
    });
});
```

Obviously, it not functioned, but, WHY?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i is always 2, isn't it? Also what i are you incrementing and decrementing on your click functions. It looks global to me, which would mean it starts out undefined.

Comment: pls make a demo of your work so far on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I will be the image number... 2 is only a example... if the user click in the seventh image, i will be equals 7... I need a function that make him click in a left/right navigation and changes the i value to see the back/forward image, like the Cycle plugin. Here are my job, http://jsfiddle.net/YkRr2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 2;
var max = 10;
$('.gallery a').click(function(event) {
    var path = 'images/display/'
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.lightbox').removeClass('preloader').fadeIn();
    if ($(this).hasClass('leftnav')) {
      if(i== max) return;  
      i++;
    }
    else {
       if(i==0) return;
        i--;
    }
    $('.display').html('<img src="'+path+i+'.jpg" />').addClass('imgdisplay');
});
```

Comment: You also need to accept the `event` variable in the onclick function to call `preventDefault()` on it.

Comment: Here are!! http://codepen.io/Mpleandro/full/CaAip or here, in JsFinddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YkRr2/

Comment: Guys! I did the code! See here how it function... the difference was the location of my var and i put a ('display').attr to give a refresh in the new image obtained by the variable i, changed on click!!!  http://codepen.io/Mpleandro/full/CaAip